# Using Socket io to make a real-time chat app with react

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I was working on making a simple chat app by using react and socket io. But I am kind of stuck in with how to make a one-to-one chat app and group chat app. That is when I started to watch online sources and I found the following two sources but their way is confusing me about how socket io generally works. In, both cases, an id(unique to each user) is generated from the client and sent to the server in different ways. But, how is the socket io connection working in each case? what is generally the difference between the two cases in terms of how socket io is working? also in the second code, why is there a join, to one's id? is it used for private self messaging(like someone messaging themselves or a room that has only one person and that person is he/she him/herself?
generally, it would be great if you guys can point out, how one can go and do one-to-one or group chats?

```
//some other code
const socket = require("socket.io");
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on ${process.env.PORT}`)
);
const io = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  },
});

global.onlineUsers = new Map();
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  global.chatSocket = socket;
  socket.on("add-user", (userId) => {
    onlineUsers.set(userId, socket.id);
  });

  socket.on("send-msg", (data) => {
    const sendUserSocket = onlineUsers.get(data.to);
    if (sendUserSocket) {
      socket.to(sendUserSocket).emit("msg-recieve", data.msg);
    }
  });
});
```

and there is also another one, which uses the following

```
const io = require('socket.io')(5000)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  const id = socket.handshake.query.id
  socket.join(id)
  socket.on('send-message', ({ recipients, text }) => {
    recipients.forEach(recipient => {
      const newRecipients = recipients.filter(r => r !== recipient)
      newRecipients.push(id)
      socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit('receive-message', {
        recipients: newRecipients, sender: id, text
      })
    })
  })
})
```